# Downloading and installing files

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. When I first got my PC I tried downloading a client to play runescape on (Orion Pro) The file downloaded fully but never gave me an option to install? Also the same for java player. All I got was the downloaded file but no place to load the startup process, just a bunch if files which I really don't understand. If anyone could help with what I need to do that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a Windows mentality about installing files which you have to lose in order to succeed in installing files in Ubuntu. In general the extension suffix on the downloaded file will tell you how to install it.

First of all you should search for the application you want in the Ubuntu Software Center. For example Java (OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime) can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center.

If that doesn't work, files that end with the extension .deb are easy to install. Just double click on the .deb file and it will open for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.

To install the RuneScape client in Ubuntu open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hikariknight/unix-runescape-client
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unix-runescape-client
```

These commands will work on all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. The ppa:hikariknight/unix-runescape-client is an Ubuntu Launchpad PPA (Personal Package Archive) for the RuneScape Unix Game Client. Packages installed from PPAs are not officially supported by Ubuntu, but adding the PPA to your software sources makes it possible to install packages from that PPA, either in the Ubuntu Software Center or from the terminal. The unix-runescape-client package is preconfigured to use the Java package from the Ubuntu Software Center by default.

You can also install generic Linux binary files in Ubuntu. These files are usually downloaded as an archive in various archive formats, the most common of which is the .tar.gz format. There will often be a file in the archive called INSTALL (or sometimes README) which contains the instructions for how to install the package from that archive. These instructions are sometimes explicit and easy to follow, but sometimes the installation instructions are incomplete or make unrealistic assumptions about the knowledge of the person who is installing the package, so it is easier to install the same package from a .deb file if there is one available.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ubuntu.

You need to be aware that Ubuntu is not Windows, and therefore will not run windows applications you download from the internet.

But don't worry. Most likely there are alternative software available for you.

i don't know much about RuneScape, but Orion Pro seems to be a recording software. Check up on www.winehq.org for information about how to play RuneScape on Ubuntu.

Java plugins are available in the software center, or from installing ubuntu-restricted-extras as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Else you can try installing icedtea java plugin with:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

That should enable java support in your browsers at least.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should forget about Windows-style download an installer and install the software method. Ubuntu uses deb packages, mostly they are in repositories, so, you should install from there. 
Perhaps you are familiar with Android and Google Play: so, it is something similar. Locate Software Center in your Ubuntu system, and search there for the needed softwares.

Time to time it happens that some software isn't in Software Center. Then you have to search for a PPA repository, add that and install from there. Just if none of the methods above didn't succeded, you can download and install from untrusted locations, but I think that this is not advisable for a beginner.

Try to read and learn as much as possible about Ubuntu and Linux, because this is somehow a different world.